# Unable to generate a php library project using maven

Tags: php, maven-3

Hi I'm trying to create a PHP library project using Maven. I've followed all the instructions from [Maven for php](http://www.php-maven.org/). I'm working on a windows 8.1 machine.
Here's what i've doen

- Installed Maven 3.3.1
- Installed php 5.5.12

I've also put the following in the settings.xml file in my .m2 repo.

```
<settings>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile-php-maven</id>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>release-repo1.php-maven.org</id>
                    <name>PHP-Maven 2 Release Repository</name>
                    <url>http://repos.php-maven.org/releases</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>snapshot-repo1.php-maven.org</id>
                    <name>PHP-Maven 2 Snapshot Repository</name>
                    <url>http://repos.php-maven.org/snapshots</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>release-repo1.php-maven.org</id>
                    <name>PHP-Maven 2 Release Repository</name>
                    <url>http://repos.php-maven.org/releases</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>snapshot-repo1.php-maven.org</id>
                    <name>PHP-Maven 2 Snapshot Repository</name>
                    <url>http://repos.php-maven.org/snapshots</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>profile-php-maven</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

But when I execute the below command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.phpmaven -DarchetypeArtifactId=php5-lib-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.0.2 -DgroupId=org.sample -DartifactId=my-app -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I get the following error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate
>   (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does
>   not exist  (org.phpmaven:php5-lib-archetype:2.0.2) -> [Help 1]

Looks like the archetype is not found in the default repository.

please advise

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Maven for PHP](http://www.php-maven.org/) is no longer supported. Last changes:

- page: 2012-09-08 (see [home page](http://www.php-maven.org/))
- sources: 2012-11-22 (see [source repository](https://github.com/php-maven/maven-php-plugin))

I would recommend changing tools. Maybe [Phing](https://www.phing.info/)?